# Mongoose create record containing an array of objects (Cast to Array failed)

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Attempting what seems like a fairly straightforward create using object:

```
var toSave = {
  person_number: "rjq8900",
  person_name: "john smith",
  cars: [{
    car_id: "fordTaurus1994",
    make: "ford",
    model: "taurus",
    purchased: "31-Aug-15",
    price: "1650"
  }]
}
```

into schema:

```
var People = new Schema({
  person_number: String,
  person_name: String,
  cars:[{
    car_id: String,
    make: String,
    model: String,
    purchased: Date,
    price: Number
  }]
})
```

via:

```
People.create(toSave, function(e, doc){
  console.log(e);
});
```

And I'm getting:

```
errors:{
  cars:{
    [CastError: Cast to Array failed for value "[object Object]" at path "cars"]
  }
}
```

Am I missing something blatantly obvious here?

**EDIT** 
Added "car_id" field to my example. My actual schema/document is large and somewhat dynamically created. I'm trying to be as precise as possible without being too accurate for disclosure purposes. I can't post actual data here.

Comment: @inspired good thought. I tried it, and confirmed that the date objects are being passed correctly. Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/embedded-documents.html), you should handle your embedded documents like so:

```
var Cars = new Schema({
  car_id: String,
  make: String,
  model: String,
  purchased: Date,
  price: Number
});

var People = new Schema({
  person_number: String,
  person_name: String,
  cars:[Cars]
});

mongoose.model('People',People);
```

> This way your The `cars` key of your People documents will then be an
>   instance of `DocumentArray`. This is a special subclassed `Array` that can
>   deal with `casting`, and has special methods to work with embedded
>   documents.

You could then add a cars document like so:

```
// retrieve my model
var Car= mongoose.model('Car');

// create a person
var person = new Person();

// push car
person.cars.push(
{
    car_id: "fordTaurus1994",
    make: "ford",
    model: "taurus",
    purchased: "31-Aug-15",
    price: "1650"
  }
);

person.save(function (err) {
  if (!err) console.log('Success!');
});
```

Comment: Had to modify a ton of stuff (my semi-dynamic schema reader was relying on `schema.tree` for some things) but this worked beautifully! Thanks, I've been at this one for hours.